# How to create column indexes in cassandra through my java module?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, hector

I want to make a query on cassandra with an '=' sign. To improve performance, I want to create indexes for columns.

I am loading data to cassandra with sstables and sstableLoader

Comment: Are you attempting to create secondary indexes on an existing column family? Which version of Cassandra?

Comment: I am using Cassandra 1.1.2. I want to create secondary indexes to columns when I am creating those columns along with creating column families. I want to do this with my java module. (Currently I'm using Hector and could not find a way for this yet)

Comment: actually in more clear manner i want to do the following command in java code, here they have added secondary index to age, I want this to be done in java.........      create column family Users
    with key_validation_class=LexicalUUIDType
    and comparator=AsciiType
    and column_metadata=[
        { column_name: 'lastname', validation_class: AsciiType }
        { column_name: 'password', validation_class: AsciiType }
        { column_name: 'age', validation_class: LongType, index_type: KEYS }
        { column_name: 'email', validation_class: AsciiType }];

Comment: I create the column family at dynamically and after that at data load time I give column name and value(with creating sstableseg- eventWriter.addColumn(bytes("columnname"),    bytes(<valuse>), timestamp);)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correctly, you want to create secondary index on a column family through Hector. The following discussion on the hector mailing list has the example code:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.hector.user/3151

Comment: thanx that is very useful , also help me in creating counter columns in column families dynamically via my  java module.